# How to write a CSV table to docx using python

Tags: python, csv, docx

I have a `CSV` file like the following one:

```
user,password,company
Administrator, 123456, test_company
test_user1, abcdf, test_company1
test_user2, 789, test_company2
```

This should be a table with `user`, `password` and `company` as headers.

How can I write this structure as a table in a `docx` file using python?

Comment: Do you need this to be in pure python? Because you could use `pandas.dataframe.to_latex()` and then use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). E: Obviously, you can call `pandoc` from python, but maybe you can't use pandoc.

Comment: No, I'm open to all hints, but if it's possible, I prefer stay on pure Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import docx 
import csv

doc = docx.Document()

with open('csv.csv', newline='') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f) 

    csv_headers = next(csv_reader)
    csv_cols = len(csv_headers)

    table = doc.add_table(rows=2, cols=csv_cols)
    hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells

    for i in range(csv_cols):
        hdr_cells[i].text = csv_headers[i]

    for row in csv_reader:
        row_cells = table.add_row().cells
        for i in range(csv_cols):
            row_cells[i].text = row[i]

doc.add_page_break()
doc.save("data.docx")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. It works. What about whether the table is not a static one? I mean, if I don't know table dimension (rows x columns). How can I add this kind of dynamic table?

Comment: @Riccardo, It looks like you can use `rows=2`, then just add as many rows as you need.  On the other hand, you can't do the same thing with cols.  So, do `num_cols = len(csv_headers)`, then `cols=num_cols`.

Comment: I grabbed your hint, but I didn't figure out how to change your code. EDIT: I think I fixed! thank you

Comment: @Riccardo, I also made the changes in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better solution, but well. You need [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) on your computer.

Suppose your csv is in `tt.csv`. You can do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tt.csv', header=None)
df.to_latex('tt.tex', index=False, header=False)
subprocess.run(['pandoc', '-s', '-f' ,'latex', 'tt.tex', '-o', 'tt.docx'])
```

That's it.

Comment: @Riccardo sure thing, my answer is a bit of an overkill :)